# Has anyone else had troubles with YouTube embed HTML5 player with class="html5-video-content" display size issues.

Tags: html, video, youtube, embed

I'm having an issue getting the video playback to display the proper size.

I'm using **?html5=1** to display the video, however, I'm getting an odd occurrence where the video Thumbnail and Player is the correct size, but the playback is smaller, leaving a thick black margin of about 20px around the left, bottom, and right.

Included below are a series of screenshots, that show the progression of my issue.

My space and size is this:

```
<iframe class="videoplayer" width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/vSYz7764j0I?html5=1&rel=0&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The actual player space maintains the 560px x 315px, but I've paused and measured the video, and it's much smaller. Using Firebug, I've found that YouTube has some code that they generate, which is this:

```
<div class="html5-video-content" style="width: 507px; height: 285px; left: 26.6667px; top: 0px;"></div>
```

The odd thing is that when I go to the controls of the player, and select HD, it fixes the display; "even" if I go back to default or 360.

**SCREENSHOT PROGRESSION** (I had to remove my screens because of low reputation. sorry)
1. Open up the Modal, containing the embedded iframe
2. Start playing the video - large black margins left, bottom, right
3. In Controls, set to 720 HD - this fixes the size issue
4. In Controls, set back to 360 SD or Default - problem still fixed

**NOTE**: The problem does not get fixed by initially resizing to a different SD size, It has to resize "up", then it can be resized back down.

**Additional Info**: Default is 360, and the only other size is 720.

Comment: If anyone stumbles upon this, I've figured it out. The problem comes from the size that YouTube gives as the default, and that the width and height seem to handle the sizing of the player and the video separately. In may case, the player needed the 560px width to properly size the player and iframe, however, the height needed to be adjusted to make the video properly fit within the player. This was very odd, but it worked once I made that edit.

Comment: Can you please clarify what the code change you made was?

Comment: Sure, it seems like the default size that they give you are off a bit. I maintained using the 560px wide for the iframe size, but then I changed the height from 315px to 345px, which resized the actual video within the iframe. It doesn't really make sense to me "why" this works, but it's worked on all of the videos that I'm using on the site, so I won't argue with the results...